# CSS file revisions not recognized when reloading page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have had this problem for a while now. There are times when I am working on a CSS file and I overwrite it by FTP-ing via FileZilla. When I reload the page to check my new changes, it doesn't load my new file. I can clear cache, reload, reset, etc, nothing will reload it. It happens the same accross IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, etc. If I delete the CSS file from the server, it is still being loaded up, but I don't know from where. The website is WordPress based but has no cache plugins. After a while, it will load the new file, but a while has to pass.

http://skyhangout.com/bellavistadental/

What in the world is causing this?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Sometimes I've found that firefox will cache my css files even if I clear the cache. A quick way to get around it is to add a version number to the end of the file. Everytime you update the version number it will check for a new file: ie mystylesheet.css?v=1

Comment: @Jade Good call on the version numbers. Not only will this help alleviate cache issues, but it also helps if you need to roll back your code for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few times! I can be obvius, but do you delete the cash from the dashboard? It is the only thing thats works to me (sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

A common and effective method of cache busting is to append a query string `?example` to the end of the stylesheet link:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://skyhangout.com/bellavistadental/wp-content/themes/tOrange/style.css?v=1.0" />`

Then you just change `?v=1.0` to `?v=1.1` or something similar each time you update the CSS file.

This makes the browser think it's a new file, so any previously cached version is ignored and the new CSS file is downloaded.

If this doesn't fix it, it's not a browser cache issue, and is probably server-side caching (on the server level, not the Wordpress level), which you'd need to speak with your webhost about.